# Swift: How to pass data from TableViewController to Details VC

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Table View Controller with 3 variables from Firebase Database.
I would like to pass this data to Details View Controller.
At now, I have only "title"(label1) passed from TableVC to Details VC.

How could I pass rest of data (label2 and label3) to DetailsVC?

**MondayTableVC:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell_Monday")

        let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = conf[indexPath.row]
        let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        // print(message)

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = message["title"]

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = message["place"]

        let label3 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        label3.text = message["date"]


        return cell!

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



        let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = conf[indexPath.row]
        let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let monDetails = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mondayDetails") as! MondayViewController
        monDetails.title = message["title"]


        monDetails.mondayDetailDict = message
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(monDetails, animated: true)


    }
```

**Monday(Details)ViewController:**

```
class MondayViewController: UIViewController {

    var mondayDetailDict: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary()


    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


   }
```

Could someone help to resolve this challenge?

Comment: create your own cell subclass with UILabel outlets, and put data inside cell.

Comment: why don't you send the entire `message` to the `MondayViewController`?

Comment: @Adeel How could I do this?

Comment: @gryzek In fact you are already sending the entire `message` dictionary in this line `monDetails.conferenceDetailDict = message`.

Comment: @Adeel Yes, but only the "title" is showing. Nothing more. How can I improve this?

Comment: @gryzek please share the code of __MondayViewController__. Need to see how are you handling this information there.

Comment: @Adeel I edited my question about MondayVC.

Comment: @gryzek Now tell me what's the issue? What are you not able to do?

Comment: @Adeel I can't display variables from MondayTableVC in MondayDetailsVC. I would like to see the same in MondayDetailsViewController like in MondayTableVC. Now, it's just showing only a "title". But for example: "place" doesn't display. And I don't know what I should implement to work this properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126645/discussion-between-adeel-and-gryzek).

Comment: why not use `performSegue(withIdentifier...)`  and use `override func prepareForSegue(...)` to pass the necessary information?

Comment: @MikeG I have a cells with particular variables from database in MondayTableVC. When I click on particular cell, in MondayDetailsVC there should be showed this data from MondayTableVC but on the one all screen. Just it. I've a problem with passing this data from TableVC do DetailsTableVC. Do you know how to implementyour solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = conf[indexPath.row]
        let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let monDetails = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mondayDetails") as! MondayViewController
        monDetails.title = message["title"]
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CellClass

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        monDetails.field2 = label2.text

        let label3 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        monDetails.field3 = label3.text

        monDetails.conferenceDetailDict = message
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(monDetails, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. "cell?" is bad definition in Xcode 8. That code can't be implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not assigning the value to `label1`. Change the `MondayViewController` to this:

```
class MondayViewController: UIViewController {

var mondayDetailDict: Dictionary<String, String> = Dictionary()

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label1.text = mondayDetailDict["place"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
}
```